# What is the significance of Jimmy's restaurant scenes in Better Call Saul?

Tags: better-call-saul

In S01E01 in a starting scene, we see Jimmy working in a restaurant. We see similar scenes at the start of many episodes.

How did Jimmy end up working there? and What is the significance of those scenes?

PS: Just FYI, I am in the middle of season 3 (so try to be careful with potential spoilers).

Comment: Breaking Bad explains it all. You need to see the end of the series especially to understand. I'm going to leave it at that and not make this an official answer either.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan While I think BrBa explains how he got there, it doesn't explain what it really means, as the point of doing a prequel/sequel with Jimmy is to analyze whom he really is. As Bob Oderick has stated on a few occasions, Saul Goodman was never who Jimmy really was--so it's impart about learning how Saul Goodman is born and in part about if Jimmy can ever go back to being Jimmy again, because we are learning about what Jimmy lost and/or if he can still somehow come out on top??!!

Comment: Jimmy? Who the hell's Jimmy? The guy at the Cinnabon is Gene Takavic!

Comment: These are scenes about a year after Breaking Bad

Comment: Or, to give him his full title, [His Most Royal and Holy Majesty Gene Takavic-Steinholz XIV of Plön](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2024/jan/30/better-call-saul-star-bob-odenkirk-related-king-charles)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know yet to what point or end the future scenes will have.

*(About the Season 4 Opening Future Scene:)*

On this week's edition of the Better Call Saul Insider podcast (via The Wrap), a brand new, quite intriguing curveball has been thrown into the mix when it comes to those aforementioned flash-fowards. While speaking on the program, Gilligan, Gould, and Odenkirk suggested that these sequences might be set prior to the events of Breaking Bad's series finale, and that the person "Gene" most fears the wrath of is possibly.

They do however take place [before](https://screenrant.com/better-call-saul-flashforwards-walter-white-death/) *Breaking Bad* ends between episodes 5.15 & 5.16.

The general idea here is to realize that there are "3" personas of Jimmy McGill, with "Saul Goodman" really being a kind of mask Jimmy comes to wear. It's unclear what exactly "Gene's" Cinnabon-future (and back at the mall) implies for Jimmy, except to say that he has been living a very isolating and solitary life style in order to stay under the radar and it's hard to imagine Jimmy being able to do this for very long, given his need to constantly talk and socialize with other people.

There are characters still currently alive in *Better Call Saul* that didn't seem to exist during the events of *Breaking Bad*, and at least one of those characters, or even a character that isn't alive currently, could be fundamental to where ever these future scenes are going or will land, as Jimmy's brother, Kim, and Nacho are the character's deeper ties to whom he truly is or what he really wants.

Comment: "They do however take place before Breaking Bad ends between episodes 5.15 & 5.16" — [as stated on the podcast](https://overcast.fm/+ELPzbyEwY/20:45) your quote mentions, the writers haven't defined when the Gene Takovic sequences take place in relation to _Breaking Bad_. Totally could be between 5.15 and 5.16, but could be after 5.16.

Comment: I have checked Google Maps though, and if you're driving from a remote undisclosed location in New Hampshire to Albuquerque, it really doesn't extend the trip much if you make a quick stop in Omaha. [How many Cinnabons can there be?](https://locations.cinnabon.com/search?query=omaha&referrerPageUrl=https://locations.cinnabon.com/)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I'm not caught up on the latest season, so I don't know what has been "added" to the future sequences, and sure, maybe it won't add up to that much, but the point of it,is to TEASE if it will or won't and to wait and see. At the time I wrote this, this was all there was on the matter that I could find (as the question was about what it MEANS), but I do believe I have heard BO refer to Gene as "another" persona, implying it is significant somehow...

Comment: Sure, I’m just correcting your sentence. You said the scenes “do” take place between 5.15 and 5.16 — the show’s creators actually said, at the time you wrote your answer,  that they may or may not.

Answer (score 2):

> How did Jimmy end up working there? and What is the significance of those scenes?

Towards the end of *Breaking Bad*, after

> Hank is killed,

Walt’s involvement in the drug business is exposed, and as a consequence, so is Saul’s. We see Saul and Walt in the basement of the vacuum-repair shop, as their new identities are being created to allow them to escape jail.

As Saul remarks to Walt, the best he can hope for is to be manager of a Cinnabon in Omaha. True to his word, he achieves this glittering dream*, which is what we see in the black-and-white season-opening scenes in *Better Call Saul* — our lead character, after the events of both shows, living his life as best he can.

As of the season 5 opening scene, we learn that someone has recognised Saul from his Albuquerque days, putting him in danger of being found by the police. He calls the vacuum-repair shop to get yet another new identity set up, but then changes his mind, and says he’ll handle the situation himself.

It seems likely that the last episode or two** of *Better Call Saul* will show us what Fate, Cinnabon, and Omaha have in store for Gene/Saul/Jimmy.

* <sub>We’re not shown how, but from everything else we know about Jimmy, I figure good old-fashioned elbow grease with a sprinkling of expedient lying.</sub>

** <sub>Turns out it needed the last four!</sub>